# Is there a way to calculate the age on the 1st January based on DOB?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to calculate the age on the 1st January based on DOB?

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar - you should be able to adapt it to your needs:  [Age calculation in Cognito Forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73743/age-calculation-in-cognito-forms?rq=1)